# How to add a path prefix to globs passed to gulp.src?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, glob, gulp

Consider the following two files:

config.json

```
{
  "vendorFiles": [
    "vendor/angular/angular.js",
    "vendor/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js",
    "vendor/angular-ui-utils/modules/utils.js"
  ]
}
```

gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require("gulp"),
    concat = require("gulp-concat"),
    config = require("./config");

gulp.task("build-vendor", function() {
    gulp.src(config.vendorFiles)
        .pipe(concat("vendor.js"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("build"));
});
```

How can I eliminate the need to specify `vendor/` for each file in config.json? That file is one that is manually edited by other developers by hand, so I want to make it as hassle-free on them as possible.

Ideally I'd like my gulpfile.js to take care of adding that prefix (somehow), and for my config.json to look like this:

```
{
  "vendorFiles": [
    "angular/angular.js",
    "angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js",
    "angular-ui-utils/modules/utils.js"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There may be a better way with a Gulp specific solution, but this should work.

```
var gulp = require("gulp"),
    concat = require("gulp-concat"),
    config = require("./config");

gulp.task("build-vendor", function() {
    gulp.src(config.vendorFiles.map(function(a) {return 'vendor/' + a}))
        .pipe(concat("vendor.js"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("build"));
});
```

**Demo**:
http://jsfiddle.net/AK4tP/

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do

```
var gulp = require("gulp"),
    concat = require("gulp-concat"),
    config = require("./config");

gulp.task("build-vendor", function() {
    gulp.src(config.vendorFiles, {root: 'vendor/'})
        .pipe(concat("vendor.js"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("build"));
});
```

Gulp should accept `root` option in src() although it's not documented.

Comment: This appears to only be the case when the globs start with `/`. See https://github.com/gulpjs/glob-stream/issues/42